# SQL developer - how to change a defined variable in the loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My code below is a loop that inserts some data into a table. I am trying to change the variable `&yyyymm` so that it uses a different value each time ex:**200902,200903,200904** etc.

I can't figure how to change the defined variable inside the loop.I tried `yyyymm = &yyyymm + 1;` but it doesn't seem to work and I also tried using `declare` and it doesn't work either.

How can change the `yyyymm` variable inside the loop?

```
define yyyymm = 200902;
DECLARE 
   a number(2) := 1; 
BEGIN 
   WHILE a < 3 LOOP
      insert into test_insert
      select *
      from testdata_&yyyymm;
      a := a + 1;
      --yyyymm = &yyyymm + 1;
   END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of your defined variable inside the block to increment and run the `insert` in Dynamic SQL ( `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` )  as follows.

```
define yyyymm = 200902;
DECLARE 
   a number(2) := 1; 
   yyyymm NUMBER := &yyyymm;
BEGIN 
   WHILE a < 3 LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into test_insert
      select *
      from testdata_'||yyyymm;
      a := a + 1;
      yyyymm := yyyymm + 1;
   END LOOP; 
END; 

/
```